# how to model different types of distinct set of nodes using R (igraph) or python?

Tags: python, r, csv, igraph, vertices

I need some help regarding modeling a multi columns data. I have .csv file. I have an edge list of persons their age, gender, location and diseases they are suffering from. I have drawn a bipartite graph of a person with diseases. How can i read age, gender and location in bipartite graph using igraph? I have tried the code below but it only takes 2 columns of csv to draw a network. Can anyone help how to read person attribute like age, gender and location in this case?

```
 Person   Diseases   Age    gender  location    
    Person1 Asthma  25  Female  Location1   
    Person2 Pneumonia   35  Male    Location2   
    Person3 Typhoid 40  Male    Location3   

  getwd()
    datafile <- "/d.csv"
    d_el <- read.csv(datafile)
    d_el <- d_el[, 1:4 ]
    head(d_el)
library(igraph)
 g <- graph.data.frame(d_el, directed = FALSE)
plot(g, layout = pref.layout, 
     vertex.color="black"
    )
```

i have used these line of codes. there output represents what ?

```
V(g)$Person<- d_el$Person
 V(g)$location<- d_el$location
 V(g)$location[which(V(g)$Person %in% neighbors(g, "TB"))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make the bipartite network from an edgelist, igraph reads the first two columns as nodes and events, unless you tell it otherwise. Then, you need to tell igraph the network is bipartite by adding a vector of names to the attribute "type". So, either indicate the columns with nodes and events, or reorder the columns so that "Person" and "Disease" are in the first two columns.

```
library(igraph)
d_el <- d_el[,c(1,4,2,3)] #Reorder columns
g <- graph.data.frame(d_el, directed = FALSE)
V(g)$type <- V(g)$name %in% d_el[,1]
g 
#View the igraph object and you will see it say something like 
#"IGRAPH DN-B" - the B shows it's bipartite
```

Use a similar syntax to add attributes:

```
V(g)$age <- d_el$Age
V(g)$gender <- d_el$Gender
```

To get node sets based on affiliation with "Disease", use the `neighbors` function. Get attribute information by subsetting attributes according to neighbors:

```
neighbors(g, "Asthma") #Gets all the names of nodes affiliated with Asthma
V(g)$gender[which(V(g)$name == as_ids(neighbors(g, "Asthma")))]
#Gets the gender of all those with asthma
```

To extract an igraph object that can be represented as a network (plotted as network, etc.) use `asthma <- make_ego_graph(g,1,"Asthma")`.

Comment: I have added attributes like this but how could this tells that person with name jane have age 36 while analyzing bipartite network of person with diseases ?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want. You can extract the attributes of individuals by the disease by creating a neighborhood based on that disease (so all people how have it) and extracting attributes of interest: `V(g)$gender[which(V(g)$name %in% neighbors(g, "Asthma"))]`. But you don't need a network to do this type of analysis. What exactly do you want? An example will help.

Comment: You can change node color, size, and shape to reflect different ages and genders to visually inspect these things.

Comment: when i used this line of code V(g)$gender[which(V(g)$name %in% neighbors(g, "Asthma"))] it gives                                                                        [1] 19 19 22 22 22 20 20 26 21 14  4 20 24 24 26 22 24 24 24 20  6 26 14 14 25
[26]  4  4  4  4 16 16 18  7 17 17 13  9 10 15  8  8  9 18 23 23 23  9  8  8 15
[51]  8  8 10 10 17 11 13 13 15                                                                  it shown above results. these values are represents what?

Comment: it would be really really helpful if you shared your data by editing your question to add the data structure. (If you can.) Run `dput(d_el)` and copy and paste the output into your question. Hard to do things without the data.